# Is the following IP address mask legal?

Tags: subnet, netmask, mask

### Is this subnet mask is valid or not???

binary value of this  255.224.252.0 is

11111111.11100000.11111100.00000000
255.224.252.0

is it a legal subnet mask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not valid. A subnet mask needs to be continuously 1-filled from the left. This is the reason why you can use the alternative notation with `/x`, where *x* describes the number of 1-bits (the size of the network prefix).

It basically specifies which bits from the left identify a network and which bits (the 0s on the right) need to be ignored as they differ for each node on that subnet.

Implementations could use a mask with embedded 0 bits for doing boolean operations (and-masking), but it does not make much sense in a world where routes for networks and subnets  are based on prefixes for all other machines and routers.

The [Wikipedia article on Classless Inter Domain Routing (CIDR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)) lists the history, justification and reference RFCs.

Comment: If so ,what about           
255.255.156.0                                                                                         11111111. 11111111. 11111111. 10011100  it ends correctly but 156 doesn't give 1s in a row such as 11110000

Comment: Same problem. A valid Prefix for 4 bit wide net is `/28` (32-4) aka `mask 255.255.255.240` only. It results in `11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000`